# How do I play more than one video with AvPlayer?

Tags: xcode

I have added a video to a button using AvPlayer, and it works. But I don't know how to add more buttons, with each button playing its own video.  How would I do this? [Here is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVh3e.jpg)

Comment: By duplicating the same function you are using for the button and rename it you also might need to configure the player in the tap function as a start that should be ok but it's not the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each button needs it's own `IBAction` and perhaps move the assignment of the `AVPlayer` to the `AVPlayerViewController` into the action methods. then you have one player vc that you assign a player to as needed.

It also doesn't appear you need to hold onto the `AVPlayer` just the `AVPlayerViewController`.

i.e delete line 17, move lines 27-30 to before 45. Copy the idea from `playButtonTapped`, after the modifications, to create methods for however many other buttons you want. (Then look at those methods and find a way to consolidate as they will have a lot of identical code that could be refactored).

Also, take a look at lines 23 & 25, pretty sure they are doing nothing for you…